# Parathread not producing block on Rococo registered using CoreTime

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, rococo, parachain-collator, parathread, coretime

I am trying to list a parathread on Rococo using core time. I have followed all instructions mentioned [here](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/parachain-consensus-updates-coretime-asynchronous-backing-scalability/4396/8). I followed below steps:

1. I registered a ParaId and onboarded Parathread as [usual](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/acquire-a-testnet-slot/#register-as-a-parathread) but didn't request parachain slot because I wanted to try agile core time.
2. After onboarding, started a collator to sync with rococo.
3. Once synced, I executed below extrinsic successfully:
   [image]
4. I also received successful event message:

[image]

But on Rococo parathread page, it is still displaying as :

[image]

And not producing blocks.

Can somebody please help me to understand if I have missed any step?